# How can I make a customizeable widget area?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I know that I can go and change my theme's style.css file to change the background color of my widget areas, or if I make a custom widget area, I can give that a specific class and thus a custom background image in the style.css, but I need to give the user control for a few widget areas.

I have searched and searched and have not found any relevant information.  Does anybody have any idea how I could do this?  I really don't know how to make a widget AREA customizeable, and I would really appreciate any pointers in the right direction or assistance that anyone can provide.

**EDIT**

To be clear, I know how to add a custom widget area to my site.  I have no idea how to add a customizeable option to the widget area, rather than a custom widget.  As far as I understand it, widget areas are a set thing, are they not?  Any pointer to a theme that does this would be greatly appreciated, as all of my google searches only end up pointing me to how to create a custom widget area, rather than a customizeable widget area.

Comment: Find a free template that does this crack open the source and draw inspiration from what's happening under the hood

Comment: Do you just want to be able to add widget specific styles? Like a custom class to each widget?

Comment: you need to implement theme options where you allow user to change settings you want

Answer (score 0):

Check the following two links if it is helpful for you.

```
http://theme.fm/2011/06/tutorial-creating-a-twitter-widget-for-wordpress-91/
http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/building-custom-wordpress-widgets/
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of your question is that you are looking for a way to allow the client/admin to modify the widgets that are displayed on any given page/post (rather than modify the widgets themselves).

This is a problem I have tried various ways to solve, never adequately imo.  First of all there's the option to create a widget area for each page dynamically.  I've seen it in commercial themes, I've done it myself, it is not without it's problems as you can see here - [Register new widget position moves existing widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501218/register-new-widget-position-moves-existing-widgets)

There are plugins that can do this, again not without their drawbacks. This plugin;

http://www.codeandmore.com/products/wordpress-plugins/wp-page-widget/
http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-page-widget/

Is great, I  love it. BUT it does not work on custom page template, be aware (I've not looked at modifying to allow this, I've seen a post by the developers saying they have no intention of adding this).

There is this plugin - http://strategy11.com/display-widgets/ by the developer of the Formidable plugin, for me it makes the widget area far too complex if you have a lot of widgets and a lot of pages.

Finally there is what I ended up doing recently - using this code by Chris Coyier

http://digwp.com/2010/04/call-widget-with-shortcode/

To do my own custom code using the Wordpress function the_widget (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_widget) to deploy certain widgets on a page by page basis.